# How to find new fixed coordinates that are overlaying a rotated image?

Tags: javascript, c#, rotation

Have an rendered image of a PDF page that is rotated from it's original position and I need to display and rotate (via HTML) all of the form fields in the PDF positions manually to line up with the rotated image.  The example below shows the original start position of everything (green field) and where I need the field to show up after the rotation is completed (red field).  There are a lot of rotation examples out there but they seem to focus on rotating from the 0,0 axis instead of a variable center point (which in my scenario is the center of the document).

[image: Example]

[Here's the demostration in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qi1Z8xokl5juq8KCRSBG?p=preview)

Here's the C# code that doesn't appear to be working properly because it's rotating around the 0,0 axis or something.  It keeps repositioning the rectangle lower and to the right.

```
public static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, Point centerPoint, double angleInDegrees)
{
    double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
    double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);
    double x = (cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) - sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X);
    double y = (sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) + cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y);
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: do you only rotate the image by factors of 90 degrees?

Comment: Yes - it will only be factors of 90, correct.

Comment: 0,0 is usually he top left hand corner of the object with X to the left being positive and y going down being positive.

Comment: Yeah, this is all coming from PDF so they use the bottom left corner as 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it figured out. The whole cos/sin stuff was way overkill.

[Here's the plunker doing the same thing in javascript](https://plnkr.co/edit/RjW6s9BG9UDPT9UOFPx3?p=preview)

```
public static CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel RotatePoint(CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel page, CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel field, int angleInDegrees)
{
    double newX, newY;

    switch (angleInDegrees) {

        case 90:
        case -270:
            newX = page.Width - field.Y - field.Height;
            newY = field.X;
            return new CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel(newX, newY, field.Height, field.Width);

        case 180:
        case -180:
            newX = page.Width - field.X - field.Width;
            newY = page.Height - field.Y - field.Height;
            return new CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel(newX, newY, field.Width, field.Height);

        case -90:
        case 270:
            newX = field.Y;
            newY = page.Height - field.X - field.Width;
            return new CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel(newX, newY, field.Height, field.Width);

        default:
            return new CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel(field.X, field.Y, field.Width, field.Height);
    }
}

public class CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel
{
    public CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel() {}

    public CoordinatesAndDimensionsModel(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }

    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```